# keep getting 'Unexpected '(space)' error?

Tags: javascript, jslint

in jsLint i keep getting this  5 errors  :

'Unexpected '(space)' case summer.

'Unexpected '(space)' case winter.

'Unexpected '(space)' case fall.

'Unexpected '(space)' case autumn.

'Unexpected '(space)' case spring.

```
var season = prompt("what is your favourite  season");
switch (season) {
case "summer": 
alert("i love summer too");
break;
case "winter": 
alert("i love winter too ");
break;
case "spring": 
alert("i love Spring  too");
break;
case "fall": 
alert("i love Fall  too");
break;
case "autumn": 
alert("i love autumn  too");
break;
```

Comment: It's hard to help with a linting error with your code formatted like that. Most likely there's extra space *somewhere* around your case statements, but we can't know unless the code is shown here as it actually is in file. I would look for extra spaces after your "case" statements, honestly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read have a look at the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In your particular question, you can use the code format to better show your error message. Also, the code that causes this error would be necessary to help you.

Comment: It is just a code formatting message. If you don't want to see them, either make sure you do not put extra white spaces where they aren't needed; or turn on the option to ignore white space mess

Answer (score 0):

There's enough going on here that it's probably best to point you to the JSLint instructions to see what's going on for the future. You can find them here: http://jslint.com/help.html

But here's what's up for your question...

**TL;DR**: Mainly it's complaining that you have trailing spaces after your `case` statements.

Turn this...

```
case "summer": // <<< there's a space after the colon
```

... into this...

```
case "summer":// <<<< now there's not!
```

---

**Longer:**

You could get around your spacing errors by adding a **[JSLint Directive](http://jslint.com/help.html#directives)** to the top of your file. The one you want here is [`white:true`](http://jslint.com/help.html#white), which indicates that you want to, "Tolerate whitespace mess".

```
/*jslint: white:true */
var season = prompt("what is your favourite  season");
// ...
```

But now you'll have a whole slew of new things to fix...

- Expected 'switch' to be in a function.
- Undeclared 'prompt'.
- Undeclared 'alert'.

The first is easy enough; you just wrap in a function.

The second two are there because you haven't told JSLint what context to expect, and it's not sure if `alert` and `prompt` are valid calls. You could tell it `alert` and `prompt` are globals with another type of directive, the [global directive](http://jslint.com/help.html#global), but remember that...

> Use of global variables is strongly discouraged, but unfortunately web browsers require their use.

So to use the globals directive, you *also* need to set the `browser` directive in the jslint comment we added earlier.

Believe it or not, this mess, below, already lints! Try it at [JSLint.com](http://jslint.com).

```
/*jslint white:true, browser:true */
/*global alert, prompt */

function seasonCheck() {
"use strict";
var season = prompt("what is your favourite  season");
switch (season) {
case "summer":
alert("i love summer too");
break;
case "winter":
alert("i love winter too ");
break;
case "spring":
alert("i love Spring  too");
break;
case "fall":
alert("i love Fall  too");
break;
case "autumn":
alert("i love autumn  too");
break;
}
}
```

But `prompt` and `alert` are special cases. Those are functions you'll use during browser development. Instead of setting them up in the global directive, use the [`devel`](http://jslint.com/help.html#devel) directive like this...

I'm also going to take off the `white:true` and clean this thing up so that it's readable... Note that there are no trailing spaces, and that we have the `case` statements lined up with the `switch`, which initially seemed odd to me.

```
/*jslint devel:true */

function seasonCheck() {
    "use strict";

    var season = prompt("what is your favourite season");

    switch (season) {
    case "summer":
        alert("i love summer too");
        break;

    case "winter":
        alert("i love winter too ");
        break;

    case "spring":
        alert("i love Spring  too");
        break;

    case "fall":
        alert("i love Fall  too");
        break;

    case "autumn":
        alert("i love autumn  too");
        break;
    }
}
```

And now we have a JSLint-happy, cleanly whitespaced piece of code. I'd probably move the `alert` to the end and assign values to a string in your switch, but JSLint is already happy.

Hope that helps, and gives you a little jump-start for using JSLint.